# MSSQL INNER JOIN WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

The following SQL Query finds orders matching certain requirements and then creates a new order (InvNum) with the invoice lines (_btblInvoiceLines) at this stage it has only created basic information.

```
DECLARE @gid varchar(50) SELECT @gid = newid()

INSERT INTO InvNum (DocType,DocState,AccountID,ucIDSOrdTempInvID) 
SELECT 4,1,AccountID,@gid 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT AccountID 
      FROM InvNum 
      WHERE ubIDSOrdConsolOrder = '1' 
      AND DocState = '1' 
      AND DocType <> '5') A


INSERT INTO _btblInvoiceLines (iInvoiceID, iStockCodeID, fQuantity) 
SELECT AutoIndex, iStockCodeID, qty 
FROM (SELECT AutoIndex, iStockCodeID, qty 
      FROM (SELECT AutoIndex,AccountId,ucIDSOrdTempInvID 
            FROM InvNum
            WHERE ucIDSOrdTempInvID = @gid) T1 
      INNER JOIN (SELECT B.iStockCodeID,A.AccountID,sum(B.fQuantity) AS qty 
                  FROM (SELECT * 
                        FROM  InvNum  
                        WHERE ubIDSOrdConsolOrder = '1' 
                        AND DocState = '1' 
                        AND DocType <> '5') A    
                  INNER JOIN (SELECT * 
                              FROM _btblInvoiceLines) B ON A.AutoIndex = B.iInvoiceID 
                  GROUP BY iStockCodeID, AccountID) T2 ON T1.AccountId = T2.AccountID) T3
```

After this the InvNum columns are all updated, this works fine. My issue is with the following, which is updating the _btblInvoiceLines of the new order and new lines with that of the old orders, that which matches: `WHERE ubIDSOrdConsolOrder = '1' AND DocState = '1' AND DocType <> '5'`

This FROM clause is what is incorrect:

```
SELECT D1.*
FROM (SELECT A.* 
      FROM _btblInvoiceLines A
      INNER JOIN (SELECT max(idInvoiceLines) as idInvoiceLines, iStockCodeID 
                  FROM _btblInvoiceLines 
                  GROUP BY iStockCodeID) B ON A.idInvoiceLines = B.idInvoiceLines) D1
      INNER JOIN (SELECT * 
                  FROM _btblInvoiceLines I1 
                  INNER JOIN (SELECT accountid,autoindex,ucIDSOrdTempInvID 
                              FROM InvNum 
                              WHERE ucIDSOrdTempInvID = @gid) I2 ON I1.iInvoiceID = I2.AutoIndex) D2 ON D1.iStockCodeID = D2.iStockCodeID 
      WHERE _btblInvoiceLines.idInvoiceLines = D2.idInvoiceLines
```

I'm at a lost of how to make D1.* pull out the information from the last original _btblInvoiceLines that was added into the new orders, D2 . The only way I believe I can do this is using the following `SELECT DISTINCT AccountID,ubIDSOrdConsolOrder FROM InvNum WHERE ubIDSOrdConsolOrder = '1' AND DocState = '1' AND DocType <> '5'` but I'm at a loss of how to put this in correctly. Sorry if this is a simple question, but I have been looking and attempting to resolve this issue for 2 days now without any luck.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you format your code with some new lines inbetween statements and tabs? I think it'll increase you chance of getting an aswer.

Comment: Thank artm, will give it a go. 

Sorry first time asking a question

Comment: What vendor of SQL are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1):

I had the `INNER JOIN` in the wrong order. I did the following and this now works correctly:

```
SELECT D1.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT AccountID, AutoIndex FROM InvNum WHERE ubIDSOrdConsolOrder = '1' AND DocState = '1' AND DocType <> '5') A1

  INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM _btblInvoiceLines) D1 ON A1.AutoIndex = D1.iInvoiceID----

  INNER JOIN (SELECT max(idInvoiceLines) as idInvoiceLines, iStockCodeID FROM _btblInvoiceLines GROUP BY iStockCodeID) I1  ON D1.iStockCodeID = I1.iStockCodeID

  INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM _btblInvoiceLines I1 INNER JOIN (select accountid,autoindex,ucIDSOrdTempInvID FROM InvNum where ucIDSOrdTempInvID = @gid) I2 ON I1.iInvoiceID=I2.AutoIndex) D2 ---- @gid
ON D1.iStockCodeID=D2.iStockCodeID

WHERE _btblInvoiceLines.idInvoiceLines = D2.idInvoiceLines
```